# What are good online resources for testing designs of an IPhone app?

Tags: mobile, design, usability-testing, users

I am looking for a tool/website that I can use to test my IPhone designs on my current users, I'd like this tool/website to upload my new designs and have a dedicated link where I can share it with my users via running an inhouse campaign inside the app.

If you know any such website, i'd really appreciate sharing it with me, or if you know any other way that you suggest to test the design.

Comment: Sorry, but questions requesting recommendations for books / software / apps / papers etc. would fall into the [shopping request](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) category and aren't really suitable to a Q&A website. The reason for this is that there is no one correct answer, and such recommended items would soon be updated and replaced with newer / better versions making the best answers redundant. Therefore you're better off visiting our Chat site for such discussions, they're not really suitable for this main site I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

[Axure.com](http://www.Axure.com) is a tool that you could use.

[ten-free-usability-testing-tools](http://econsultancy.com/uk/blog/5932-ten-free-usability-testing-tools)

What tools are you using for the design? Do you want to test only the design and not the user interactions?

Comment: I use Balsamiq to do mockups and connect them all together, and then test the interaction via both papers and Balsamiq. I only want to test design to make sure that all icons are understandable and users to confuse between them... thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [myBalsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/mybalsamiq) - the online version of Balsamiq Mockups - you can [generate a URL that you can share with your users](http://support.balsamiq.com/customer/portal/articles/235574). This seems like the easiest way to have a controlled, sharable link for usability testing. There are a series of blog posts from Balsamiq that discuss how to use various third-party usability testing services too:

- [Loop11](http://blogs.balsamiq.com/product/2012/03/19/loop11/)
- [Usabilla](http://blogs.balsamiq.com/product/2012/03/14/usabilla/)
- [Kupima](http://blogs.balsamiq.com/product/2012/04/06/kupima/)
- [UserZoom](http://blogs.balsamiq.com/product/2012/06/22/userzoom/)

And finally, there's another [Balsamiq blog post](http://blogs.balsamiq.com/product/2012/10/31/linkviewer/) that talks about using [LinkViewer](http://link-viewer.maxmondon.de/) to show your prototypes on an iOS device. Basically LinkViewer lets you navigate a hyperlinked PDF, so you can use your iPad to show off your exported Balsamiq mockups (from either myBalsamiq or the desktop version).